# LinkManager.Provider is deprecated in Sitecore 9, how to get the default provider then?

Tags: sitecore-api, upgrade, link-manager

The following code works in Sitecore 8.2 but not in Sitecore 9:

```
var provider = LinkManager.Provider;
```

The `Provider` property is not available anymore in Sitecore 9 Sitecore.Kernel, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the new Sitecore.Kernel assembly I have found the following way to get the default `LinkProvider` or your custom with the following appraches:

To get default `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider`:

```
var defaultProvider = ServiceLocator.GetRequiredResetableService<ProviderHelper<Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, LinkProviderCollection>>()?.Value?.Provider;
```

To get your custom `YourNamespace.LinkProvider`:

```
var customProvider = ServiceLocator.GetRequiredResetableService<ProviderHelper<Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, LinkProviderCollection>>()?.Value?.Provider as YourNamespace.LinkProvider;
```

**As below in the comments Pete and Mark pointed out that the `ServiceLocator` is an antipattern** so I gave a try to do it with dependency injection, and it works. The following example shows, how you can use it with `ItemResolver` and DI:

```
public class ItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    protected readonly ProviderHelper<Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, LinkProviderCollection> providerHelper;

    public ItemResolver(ProviderHelper<Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, LinkProviderCollection> providerHelper)
    {
        this.providerHelper = providerHelper;
    }

    private Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider GetSitecoreLinkProvider()
    {
        return this.providerHelper?.Provider;
    }

    private YourNamespace.LinkProvider GetCustomLinkProvider()
    {
        return this.providerHelper?.Provider as YourNamespace.LinkProvider;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
<pipelines>
  <httpRequestBegin>
    <processor type="YourNamespace.ItemResolver, YourNamespace" resolve="true" />
  </httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
```

Comment: I want to upvote, but I think that you should provide the proper way to get this. While using ServiceProvider works, it's an antipattern to standard Dependency Injection, which should be used instead, but thats probably more of an opinion, but I consider it best practice.

Comment: I second that. Going via ServiceLocator cannot - I truly hope - be the new official way of getting to the LinkProvider

Comment: @PeteNavarra so I could inject ProviderHelper<LinkProvider, LinkProviderCollection> via constructor? I will try to use DI and update the answer.

Comment: @PeteNavarra, it works like a charm with DI. Thanks for pointing this out!