# Calling ItemUrlBuilder method in Sitecore 10.1

Tags: links, link-manager

We have upgraded to Sitecore 10.1 from Sitecore 8.7.

In Sitecore 8.7 We used `MultisiteItemLinkProvider` which derives from `LinkProvider` and its obsolete in Sitecore 10.1.

In Sitecore 8.7 we use the following code in the answer. Here is the [link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11671/sitecore-multisite-cross-links-not-resolved-with-proper-hostname)

```
public class MultisiteItemLinkProvider : LinkProvider
```

Which we upgraded to Sitecore 10.1 like this

```
public class MultisiteItemLinkProvider : ItemUrlBuilder
    {
        public MultisiteItemLinkProvider(DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions defaultOptions) : base(defaultOptions)
        {
        }

        public override string Build(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {
            if (Sitecore.Context.Site == null || Sitecore.Context.Site.Name == "shell")
            {
                return base.Build(item, options);
            }
            return GetItemUrlFromBase(item, options);
        }

        protected virtual bool IsFromCurrentSite(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
            return item.Paths.FullPath.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath);
        }

        protected virtual string GetItemUrlFromBase(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {
            if (IsFromCurrentSite(item)) return base.Build(item, options);

            var website = this.GetSiteContext(item);
            using (new SiteContextSwitcher(website))
            {
                options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
                options.SiteResolving = true;
                return base.Build(item, options);
            }
        }

        private static List<KeyValuePair<string, Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext>> GetSites()
        {
            return SiteManager.GetSites()
                .Where(
                    s =>
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Properties["rootPath"]) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Properties["startItem"]))
                .Select(
                    d => new KeyValuePair<string, Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext>($"{d.Properties["rootPath"]}{d.Properties["startItem"]}",
                        new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext(new SiteInfo(d.Properties))))
                .ToList();
        }

        public virtual Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext GetSiteContext(Item item)
        {

            var site = GetSites().LastOrDefault(s => item.Paths.FullPath.ToLower().StartsWith(s.Key.ToLower()));
            return site.Value;
        }
    }
```

in the config

```
<links>
    <itemUrlBuilder type="Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <patch:delete />
    </itemUrlBuilder>

    <itemUrlBuilder type="Foundation.Multisite.Providers.MultisiteItemLinkProvider, Foundation.Multisite">
        <param desc="defaultOptions" type="Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <alwaysIncludeServerUrl>true</alwaysIncludeServerUrl>
            <languageEmbedding>always</languageEmbedding>
            <languageLocation>filePath</languageLocation>
            <lowercaseUrls>true</lowercaseUrls>
            <encodeNames>true</encodeNames>
            <useDisplayName>false</useDisplayName>
            <addAspxExtension>false</addAspxExtension>
            <siteResolving>true</siteResolving>
            <shortenUrls>true</shortenUrls>
        </param>

    </itemUrlBuilder>
</links>
```

In Sitecore 8.7 we are calling the method like this

```
LinkProvider multisiteItemLinkProvider = LinkManager.Providers["MultisiteItemLinkProvider"];
```

How can we call let's say MultisiteItemLinkProvider's GetItemUrl method in Sitecore 10.1?

Comment: Why did you inherit from ItemUrlBuilder? Should it not still be LinkProvider? The part that is obsolete is the constructor, not the class.

Comment: @MichaelWest I tried to use the existing LinkProvider code and it was working fine. The only issue I had was some of the auth sites were appending the prod site when clicking the search URL like "https://test1-sc10-auth.comhttps//test1-sc10.com/search-results#e=0&q=news". When I replaced the LinkProvider method with the ItemUrlBuilder then that issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

As you have prepared a custom item URL builder. You can inject a custom URL builder by patching the `<links/itemUrlBuilder>` configuration node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>

        <links>
            <itemUrlBuilder>
                <patch:attribute name="type">YourProjectNamespace.MultisiteItemLinkProvider, YourProjectNamespace</patch:attribute>
            </itemUrlBuilder>
        </links>
        <pipelines>
            <itemUrlBuilderExtensions>
            </itemUrlBuilderExtensions>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Also, worth to look these solutions.

1. Create a foundation `UrlBuilder` with custom pipeline
2. Extend from `LocalizableLinkProvider` If you are using SXA. The default `LocalizableLinkProvider` is actually allow us to extend but have to override `GetItemUrl(Item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions)` instead.

Credit: [Multi custom links with Sitecore 10 using ItemUrlBuilder](https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/multi-custom-links-with-sitecore-10-using-itemurlbuilder)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Sumit but I have already included this in the config. I want to know how can I call let's say GetItemUrl method in the code. I have also updated my question that this config already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work for you but you can try your custom Link provider using this way.

```
var customProvider = ServiceLocator.GetRequiredResetableService<ProviderHelper<Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, LinkProviderCollection>>()?.Value?.Provider as YourNamespace.LinkProvider;
```

Try to use this and see if you are able to achieve what you need.

Ref: [How to call custom LinkProvider](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15557/linkmanager-provider-is-deprecated-in-sitecore-9-how-to-get-the-default-provide)

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial elsewhere, it worked for me:
https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/multi-custom-links-with-sitecore-10-using-itemurlbuilder